# How to run without debugging in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In Delphi XE+ there's an option to run without debugging. Is there a way to do the same in Delphi 7? I have to manually disable/enable all the breakpoints.

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: Note that the IDE can customize the buttons to its toolbar, so adding a "Run Without Debugging" button just close to the "Run" button is easy and efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. It's undocumented. [This page](http://www.blong.com/Undocumented/IDEFeatures.htm#RunWithoutDebug7) gave me the clue.

Comment: I checked with Delphi 6. It doesn't work _out of the box_, if I understand correctly, you need to create the `dclusr.dpk` as described by the webpage linked to.

Comment: As far as I can remember, It has always worked since Delphi 1.  And even in Turbo Pascal before that.

Comment: @rohit I don't know that because I didn't use earlier versions and if it's an undocumented feature then people wouldn't know about this regardless how many versions ago it existed earlier. If it works why didn't they show it in the menu!?

Answer (score 2):

It's on the `Run` Menu in Delphi, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't have that option. Are you sure you're running Delphi 7? I added an update which shows I don't have that option.The keyboard short-cut didn't do anything

Comment: It's definitely Delphi 7. Perhaps one of my IDE add ins added it. I can't check now, but maybe DDevExtensions or CnPack added it.

Comment: It was shift-F9. The extensions you mentioned are helpful. CnPack and DDevExtensions didn't add the option.

Comment: I have that menu item too, (legal) Delphi 7 Professional (Build 4.453).